# Counting data.table entries between dates

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with a bunch of entries that have start and end dates, like so:

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1958-01-03 | 1962-10-11 |
| 2 | 1961-02-23 | 2012-04-28 |

etc.

I want to count how many of these items were in operation, by month. So I tried to do this:

```
data.table(
    month = seq(as.Date('1950-01-01','%Y-%m-%d'), as.Date('2021-09-01','%Y-%m-%d'), 'months'),
    month_end = seq(as.Date('1950-02-01','%Y-%m-%d'), as.Date('2021-10-01', '%Y-%m-%d'), 'months') -1
) %>%
    .[,count := satcat[start >= month & month_end <= end,.N]] %>%
    .[]
```

What I get, however, is an error:

```
Warning message in `>.default`(start, month):
“longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length”
Warning message in `<=.default`(month_end, end):
“longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length”
```

and `count` is the same number for all rows. Why is this happening, and what is the correct way of doing this? I feel like there should be some `apply` solution, but I can't work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for `foverlaps`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(id = 1:2, 
                 start = as.Date(c("1958-01-03", "1961-02-23")),
                 end = as.Date(c("1961-10-11", "2012-04-28")))

periods <- data.table(start = seq(as.Date('1950-01-01','%Y-%m-%d'), as.Date('2021-09-01','%Y-%m-%d'), 'months'),
                      end = seq(as.Date('1950-02-01','%Y-%m-%d'), as.Date('2021-10-01', '%Y-%m-%d'), 'months') -1)


setkey(DT, start, end)
setkey(periods, start, end)

res <- foverlaps(periods, DT, nomatch = NA)[, .(N = sum(!is.na(id))), by = .(i.start, i.end)]

plot(N ~ i.start, data = res, type = "s")
```

[image: resulting plot]

```
res[N == 2]
#      i.start      i.end N
#1: 1961-02-01 1961-02-28 2
#2: 1961-03-01 1961-03-31 2
#3: 1961-04-01 1961-04-30 2
#4: 1961-05-01 1961-05-31 2
#5: 1961-06-01 1961-06-30 2
#6: 1961-07-01 1961-07-31 2
#7: 1961-08-01 1961-08-31 2
#8: 1961-09-01 1961-09-30 2
#9: 1961-10-01 1961-10-31 2
```

Comment: This works brilliantly, thanks! Out of curiosity, is there a way to make this deal with cases where end is NA (meaning the project is still ongoing)? I've just replaced those with a date in 2022, but it feels like there should be a more elegant way.

Comment: I don't think so.